# R visualization for Text survey data

Tags: r

I have the following categorical data set, which is a survey data. I am trying to visualize the text survey data in the R studio.

Please suggest me possible options

I have created a corpus but I did not got my result as it is taking each row individually I want to take is as each fruit as seprate and visualize it
Create corpus

```
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(t1$Column))

set.seed(100)
wordcloud(words = dat$word, freq = dat$freq, random.order=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, priya. Look what I've found about your desirable outcome - https://towardsdatascience.com/create-a-word-cloud-with-r-bde3e7422e8a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code chunk plots a graph that may fit to your data:

```
# setup environment
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
# define dataframe
df = data.frame(
  id = 1:6,
  column = c('apple', 'apple, banana', 'pineapple, Cherry',
             'Cherry, Apple, Banana', 'Banana, Cherry', 'Apple, Cherry')
)
# split cells containing more than one fruit
fruits = str_split(df$column, ', ')
# bind fruits into a dataframe
fruits = do.call(rbind, lapply(fruits, as.data.frame))
fruits[[1]] = str_to_title(fruits[[1]])
names(fruits) = 'column'
# plot
ggplot(fruits) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = column)) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = 'Count') +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help, I am trying to visualize that column could you please guide m e on this if possible

Comment: what you mean with visualize? the output i provided you is not enough?

Comment: I want to visualize it in a graph form

Comment: hmmm, now i got it! i just updated my post with a graph. check it out.